# Wordpress Post From Front End formatting issues

Tags: php, wordpress, post, permissions, admin

****EDIT

Its ok now, I fixed it! Added

```
    add_action('init', 'kses_init');
```

I know that this is meant to be unsecure but the form does have a lot of validation on it, so I think it should be ok.. If anyone can think of a better way of doing this I would LOVE to know it as I am not really savvy with coding and PHP, everything I know I have taught myself via Google loool..

Thanks

---

Basically, using this site and a load of its tutorials, I managed to make a 'Post From Front Ent' form for my website. It works perfectly if you are signed in as an admin but if you are signed in on any other account it breaks down the code and strips all the HTML from the post.

I hav absolutely no clue what is wrong, I have tried setting the post to automatically get attributed to an admin but that hasnt improved a thing.

When I post in a normal account the posts look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwbIK.png

If any of you can rectify this issue I would be ridiculously appreciative!!

If you need to have a look at the code just let me know and ill paste it in!!

OK, after some advice from a mod, I  think that the bit of the code which goes worng is the post content, it strips aways all HTML from the code I put in.. The code I have for the post is below, the first bit is the definition of the strings and the second is the post script:

```
    function simple_fep_add_post(){
if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&         $_POST['action'] == 'post' ){
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() )
        return;
    global $current_user;

    $user_id        = $current_user->ID;
    $post_title     = $_POST['post-title'];
    $post_artist    = $_POST['video-artist'];
    $anti_spam   = $_POST['anti-spam'];
    $artist_twitter     = $_POST['artist-twitter'];
    $post_cat   = array(intval($_POST['post-category']));
    $twitter_trimmed = ltrim($artist_twitter, "@.");
    $video_type     = $_POST['video-type'];
    $fv_video     = $_POST['fv_video'];
    $post_content   = $_POST['posttext'];
    $tags           = $_POST['tags'];
    $headers = get_headers('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' . $fv_video);
    $user_infos = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?screen_name='.$twitter_trimmed;
    $content = '<style>.video-box{ border:1px solid #efefef;height:100%;padding:15px;background:#fff;}</style><div class="video-box"><iframe width="595" height="350" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$fv_video.'?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div><style>.desc-box{ border:1px solid #efefef;height:100%;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;padding:15px;background:#fff;}</style><div class="desc-box"><h4>description</h4>'.$post_content.'</div>';
```

THIS BIT HERE IS WHERE I DEFINE THE ERROR MESSAGES ETC - I PRETTY SURE NOTHING IS WRONG HERE

```
    if (count($error_array) == 0){

    remove_filter('pre_user_description', 'wp_filter_kses');


    function my_change_author( $data , $postarr )

    {

     $data['post_author'] = 2;

      return $data;

    }


    add_filter('wp_insert_post_data' , 'my_change_author' , '99', 2);

        $new_post = array(
            'post_author' => '2',
            'post_title'    => $post_artist. ' &ndash; ' .$post_title. ' [Guest Post] ['.$video_type.' Video] [@'.$twitter_trimmed.']',
            'post_type'     => 'post',
            'post_content'  => $content,
            'tags_input'    => $tags,
            'post_category' => $post_cat,
            'post_status'   => 'publish'
            );  


    //SAVE THE POST

    $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);

    //SET OUR TAGS UP PROPERLY

       wp_set_post_tags($pid, $_POST['tags']);

    global $notice_array;
        $notice_array = array();
        $notice_array[] = "Thank you for posting. Your post is now live. Go 
    to the homepage to view it!";
        add_action('simple-fep-notice', 'simple_fep_notices');
    } else {
        add_action('simple-fep-notice', 'simple_fep_errors');
    }
}

    }


    add_action('init','simple_fep_add_post');

    //POST THE POST YO
do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post'); "
```

Thats the end of the code

***EDIT****

After tinkering some more I am swaying towards the problem lying with WP stripping all the code from the post I.E the 'style' and 'div' tags get stripped along with the video embed code... Is there a way to stop WP from formatting what is entered?

*EDIT AGAIN***

this is the string definitions after a bit more tinkering, I have managed to get the site to post the styles now, It just keep stripping the Iframe from the post... Any ideas?

```
      global $user_ID;

    $post_title     = $_POST['post-title'];
    $post_artist    = $_POST['video-artist'];
    $anti_spam   = $_POST['anti-spam'];
    $artist_twitter     = $_POST['artist-twitter'];
    $post_cat   = array(intval($_POST['post-category']));
    $twitter_trimmed = ltrim($artist_twitter, "@.");
    $video_type     = $_POST['video-type'];
    $fv_video     = $_POST['fv_video'];
    $post_content   = $_POST['posttext'];
    $tags           = $_POST['tags'];
    $headers = get_headers('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' . $fv_video);
    $user_infos = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?screen_name='.$twitter_trimmed;
    $content = '<div style="border:1px solid #efefef;height:100%;padding:15px;background:#fff;"><iframe width="595" height="350" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$fv_video.'?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div><div style="border:1px solid #efefef;height:100%;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;padding:15px;background:#fff;"><h4>description</h4>'.$post_content.'</div>';
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's almost mandatory to show some code. If you don't know which part - well that's a good starting point for you to figure out what's wrong. Try to pinpoint where your code starts to misbehave, if you can't solve it yourself from there: come back, show the relevant code and you will more likely get an immediate response.

Comment: I just added the bit of the code where I think it all goes pete tong, I think its this bit as the actual form works fine, its when the post is submitted that the problem starts!

Comment: OK so now I have figured that WP didnt like the 'style' tags and used "div style" instead, the styling is now working, the only thing is it is still stripping the 'iframe' video from the post... Any ideas??

Comment: post your own answer as an answer and accept it. It is okay to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

Its ok now, I fixed it! Added

```
add_action('init', 'kses_init');
```

I know that this is meant to be unsecure but the form does have a lot of validation on it, so I think it should be ok. If anyone can think of a better way of doing this I would LOVE to know.